# How to insert an empty string into a field in a flow action in Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: string, power-automate, is-empty

How do you insert an empty string into a field in a flow action in Microsoft Power Automate? Google results I've found say to use a 'null' expression and it should empty the field. However, it didn't work when I was using the Excel (Business) connector for an 'update a row' action. The field retained its original value instead of being empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a null expression inside a string function will produce a blank string. This will empty/make the field blank.

[image: Flow expression string null]